# Evernote crashes when creating note using Intent

Tags: android, evernote

My app has been working for years, creating a new note in Evernote using a simple Intent (com.evernote.action.CREATE_NEW_NOTE) with EXTRA_TITLE and EXTRA_TEXT data. Suddenly, after recent Evernote app updates, Evernote crashes when I do this. Did something change in the Intent interface, or is this an Evernote bug?